# Update the distinct value of List of List Object C#

Tags: c#

I have two lists, one vulnerabilitiesScanList which is of type `VulnerabilityImportedScansListViewDto`. Inside `VulnerabilityImportedScansListViewDto` I have another list `public List<string> AssetName { get; set; }` of string type.

```
    var vulnerabilitiesScanList = new List<VulnerabilityImportedScansListViewDto>();

    public class VulnerabilityImportedScansListViewDto 
    {
        public List<string> AssetName { get; set; }
    }
```

When I get the values in `vulnerabilitiesScanList`, I have a duplicate value in `AssetName`. I want to update the value of `vulnerabilitiesScanList.AssetName` to distinct.

How can I do I am using C# 10?

I tried `vulnerabilitiesScanList.ForEach(x=> x.AssetName = (List<string>) x.AssetName.Distinct());`. It throws an exception

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Comment: @YongShun Unable to cast object of type 'DistinctIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: Did you try `vulnerabilitiesScanList.ForEach(x=> x.AssetName = x.AssetName.Distinct().ToList());` ? Missing `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try .SelectMany() than .Distinct()

```
vulnerabilitiesScanList.SelectMany(x=> x.AssetName).Distinct()
```

Comment: Still giving me duplicate values

Comment: If you have empty spaces it can make Distinct not work. In that case you can .Trim() the values and than .Distinct()

Comment: I doubt this may lead to a different results with `.ForEach`. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4DPCx). But anyway Post Owner didn't share the sample data and expected output, so the question is ambiguous